# Unexpected behavior using Enumerable.Empty<string>()

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I would expect `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` to return an empty array of strings. Instead, it appears to return an array with a single `null` value. This breaks other LINQ operators like `DefaultIfEmpty`, since the enumerable is not, in fact, empty. This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something (99% probability).

GameObject Class

```
 public GameObject(string id,IEnumerable<string> keywords) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)) {
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "id");
        }
        if (keywords==null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "keywords");
        }
        if (keywords.DefaultIfEmpty() == null) { //This line doesn't work correctly.
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "keywords");
        }
        if (keywords.Any(kw => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kw))) {
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "keywords");
        }

        _id = id;
        _keywords = new HashSet<string>(keywords);
    }
```

Test

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void EmptyKeywords() {
        GameObject test = new GameObject("test",System.Linq.Enumerable.Empty<string>());
    }
```

Comment: Please show us a small, complete reproduce of your problem. That definitely sounds peculiar.

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty<string>().Count()` is zero.  There is certainly not a null entry in it.  I can't reproduce.

Comment: Your unit-test is failing on the `Any` method? What does the test output say

Comment: adding specific issue.

Comment: What do you mean by 'This line doesn't work correctly'? What are you expecting to happen? That condition should return `false`.

Comment: [Reading the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360179(v=vs.100).aspx) would of solved you the mystery, it is crystal clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you expect this condition:

```
keywords.DefaultIfEmpty() == null
```

to evaluate to `true`. However `DefaultIfEmpty` returns a singleton sequence containing the default for the element type (`string` in this case) if the source sequence is empty. Therefore it will return a sequence containing `null`. This is not itself `null` however so the condition returns `false`.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I could have sworn I checked that, but apparently I botched a simple rtfm issue. Still kind of weird and unintuitive, but at least it's documented. Sorry bout that.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the implementation of `DefaultIfEmpty`, here is it's implementation [from the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,91fbfcebba3a1b1c).

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    return DefaultIfEmpty(source, default(TSource));
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValue) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    return DefaultIfEmptyIterator<TSource>(source, defaultValue);
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> DefaultIfEmptyIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource defaultValue) {
    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator()) {
        if (e.MoveNext()) {
            do {
                yield return e.Current;
            } while (e.MoveNext());
        }
        else {
            yield return defaultValue;
        }
    }
}
```

So what it does is if a `IEnumerable<T>` is not empty it simply returns the `IEnumerable<T>`, if the `IEnumerable<T>` is empty it returns new a `IEnumerable<T>` with one object in it with the value `default(T)`. It will never return `null` which is what your test is testing for. If you wanted to test this you would need to do

```
if(keywords.DefaultIfEmpty().First() == null)
```

However this is going to cause the `IEnumerable<string>` to be evaluated multiple times. I would drop the LINQ and just do like the LINQ method does and do it the long way (this also gets rid of the extra evaluation you had inside `new HashSet<string>(keywords)`).

```
 public GameObject(string id,IEnumerable<string> keywords) 
 {
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "id");
    }
    if (keywords==null) {
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "keywords");
    }

    _keywords = new HashSet<string>();

    using (var enumerator = keywords.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (e.MoveNext())
        {
            do 
            {
                if(e.Current == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "keywords");

                _keywords.Add(e.Current);

            } while (e.MoveNext());
        }
        else 
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "keywords");
        }
    }

    _id = id;
}
```

This makes it so you only loop once over the `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
 public GameObject(string id, IEnumerable<string> keywords) {
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "id");
    }
    if (keywords == null || !keywords.Any()
            || keywords.Any(k => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(k))) {
        throw new ArgumentException("invalid", "keywords");
    }

    _id = id;
    _keywords = new HashSet<string>(keywords);
}
```

*Improved the code with suggestions from @ScottChamberlain & @ginkner

Comment: Your `All` check is unessesary due to the `keywords.Any(kw => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kw))` check on the next line.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, my bad! I've removed the `All` as it seems from op's code that he won't allow `Any` null in keywords. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I ended up using keywords.Any rather than keywords.Count, since Any only has to check if a single item is there, whereas count requires iteration of the entire list.

Comment: @ginkner correct point, agreed. What I was trying to convey is, you can achieve your functionality without even using `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: Indeed. Apparently DefaultIfEmpty isn't really even worth using in most cases, since you'd have to create an empty collection to compare the returned collection to.

Comment: @ginkner Updated the answer, in case someone finds it useful in future. And yes, couldn't think of a real scenario where I'd use DefaultIfEmpty!